# How to hide terminal when opening a GUI application (pdf, jpg, etc), and make it reappear when closing?

Tags: terminal, window-manager

I am using a tiling WM (AwesomeWM) and `alacritty` as my default shell. When I open a file (from the terminal), it opens it in a new window, next to my terminal.

This is rather annoying and not what I would want. If I close the terminal, the PDF (`zathura`) will close too. I could minimize the terminal, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

I remember there being such a thing as "silent mode", though I'm not sure of the name. The idea is that the terminal would "disappear" when opening a PDF (or image or what not) and stay as such, until I closed the PDF, in which case, the terminal would reappear.

Not sure how it worked and I can not seem to find it. If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `xdotools`. Beside *"minimizing"* the terminal we can *unmap* it making it hidden from the window manager.

Have cleaned up and commented a script I made for this ages ago, and that I honestly rarely use, but should fit.

Nice thing with using `xdotools`, (as long as one are running X), is the control one have and tweaks one can incorporate etc. It is a valuable tool for making custom window tools. If there is a bug or a feature one want, it is easy enough to work on.

Beside hiding the terminal emulator this script also has a few options:

- `-p` position the child at same coordinates as the terminal has (before unmap).
- `-r` instead of hiding terminal, adopt it as a child of terminal. (Rather experimental and need more work if it is to work nice with various applications.)
- `-v` some verbose print
- `-h` help

With no options set it simply launch program and unmap terminal.

It also restores the terminal position when re-mapped - as this can be lost in various window managers.

Not extensively tested, but has worked fine for the little I have used it.

If using it for applications that is running and which does not spawn new instances, e.g. `qalculate`, one need to use `-n` flag or what ever, if present, for the application to start a new session.

One could of course implement *minimize* instead of / in addition to *unmap* etc.

***NB!***: Due to the site / SE breaking code by replacing spaces for tabs either copy by clicking *[edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/655571/edit)* or reident after pasting to editor. (This goes for the `<<-EOF`'s below)

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -

# Print various information, option: -v
verbose=0
# Position spawned window at X Y of terminal, option: -p
poschild=0
# Reparent to terminal
reparent=0

# ENABLE JOB CONTROL
set -m

print_help() {
    cat<<-EOF
    Usage: $(basename "$0") [OPTION] program [args ...]
      Hide terminal window by unmapping until program exits.
      Do Ctrl+C when using -r / -p if program fails.
    OPTIONS
      -p  Position child at X Y of terminal.
      -r  Reparent. Set it as child of terminal.
      -v  Verbose. Print geometry.
      -h  This help.
    EOF
}
print_geom() {
    cat<<-EOF
    WIN-ID  $WINDOW
    POS     $X $Y
    SIZE    $WIDTH $HEIGHT
    EOF
}
# DEFINES by Evil Eval
#   WINDOW (window id)
#   X Y
#   WIDTH HEIGHT
#   SCREEN
get_win_geom() {
    eval "$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowgeometry --shell)"
}
# RESTORE Terminal Geom
set_win_geom() {
    xdotool windowmove "$WINDOW" "$X" "$Y"
    xdotool windowsize "$WINDOW" "$WIDTH" "$HEIGHT"
}
# HIDE current terminal
term_hide() {
    xdotool windowunmap "$WINDOW"
}
# RESTORE Terminal
term_show() {
    xdotool windowmap "$WINDOW"
    # On remapping window can loose original position
    # Restore to pre-unmap values
    set_win_geom
}
# Position program at X Y of terminal
# Using -sync has two effects:
#   1. Need to wait for window to appear
#   2. If command fails it hangs, and we can
#      abort with Ctrl+C
# Use --onlyvisible as windows can have a range of sub-windows.
# This could likely be done better.
pos_child() {
    wid="$(xdotool search --sync --pid "$1" --onlyvisible --limit 1 --all)"
    xdotool windowmove "$wid" "$X" "$Y"
}
# Adopt the child process's window
win_reparent() {
    wid="$(xdotool search --sync --pid "$1" --onlyvisible --limit 1 --all)"
    xdotool windowreparent "$wid" "$WINDOW"
}
# Bring process to foreground after mapping, moving etc.
fg_cpid() {
    if ! kill -0 "$cpid" 2>/dev/null || ! fg %1 >/dev/null; then
        printf 'Failed\n' >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
    '-h'|--help) print_help >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
    '-v') verbose=1 ;;
    '-p') poschild=1 ;;
    '-r') reparent=1 ;;
    *) break ;;
    esac
    shift
done
get_win_geom
[ $verbose -eq 1 ] && print_geom >&2

# Order of operation can be of importance here.
# Start child before unmap
command "$@" &
cpid="$!"

[ $poschild -eq 1 ] && pos_child "$cpid"
[ $verbose -eq 1 ] && jobs -l
if [ $reparent -eq 1 ]; then
    win_reparent "$cpid"
    fg_cpid || exit 1
else
    term_hide
    fg_cpid || exit 1
    # Restore when child departs
    term_show
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell spawns processes like Zarathura as *subprocesses* that are killed when the mother process is killed. Your terminal emulator starts the shell itself as subprocess.

So, easiest solution is to *not* open things in a subprocess, but as a separate process.

You can do that for *any* process using

```
 nohup programname parameters..
```

but in your case it's even easier:

```
 xdg-open yourfile.pdf
```

opens the application that's supposed to open application/pdf files, as a separate process. This works with other file-types, too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the second one does not work, it still spawns the process next to the terminal, in a new window. - As for the first, I tried [ nohup zathura [filename] ]. It did not quite work.. (It says something about attaching to nohup.out) I guess I am doing it wrong. Can you please elaborate? Cheers. - Also, Quasimodo is right, I would prefer the terminal reappearing afterwards. (But even if it does not, I would be happy if the terminal autodissapeared.).

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found what I was talking about, so I will consider this topic closed. Feel a bit silly, but I was not able to find it for some time and than I asked.. Randomly, I found it rather quickly afterwards.

But thanks for the help!

(in case anyone is interested https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBNLzHcUtTo sorry for the cheesy name of the video.)

Cheers.